# In Flutter, how can I have an adjusting vertical layout, a mix between column and listview behavior?

Tags: flutter, listview

As far as I see, Column and ListView both have a very distinct usage when used for a base root layouting.

Column is used when the screen has few components (such as login screen). We can add some Expanded components to adjust white spaces in between, so when the keyboard is visible, the screen shrink to keep everything visible.

ListView is used when the screen has many components that potentially need scrolling. We can't use Expanded component in ListView. When using ListView, appearing keyboard does not change the white spaces, only change the size of outer ListView, while the inner content is wrapped in scroll view.

Now the problem is, how if I want to have screen like this:

- When all the contents' combined vertical size is not longer than available height quota given from parent (in this case, screen's height), then the components behave like inside Column: expanding or shrinking to fill available white spaces according to rules set by Expanded.
- When all the content's combined vertical size is longer than available height quota, then the components behave like inside ListView: all the possible expanding components will shrink into their minimum size (ignoring Expanded), and the screen is scrollable so user can see the rest of the screen below.

Is this possible to be done in Flutter? How?

EDIT: based on Reign's comment, I have isolated some code from [SingleChildScrollView manual](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html), but it looks like it still can't handle if its children contains Expanded.

```
Widget columnRoot({
  MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  AssetImage backgroundImage,
  List<Widget> children
}) =>
    LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) =>
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: backgroundImage,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
                      children: children
                  ),
                )
            )
        )
    );

Widget content(BuildContext context) => columnRoot(children: [
  Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100.0),
  Expanded(Container(color: Colors.green)), // without this line, there's no layout error
  Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 100.0),
]);
```

Error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: if you want to combined the two, instead of using listview. use ```singlechildscrollview``` as a parent and column as a child...it will act as the same

Comment: @Reign ok let me try first. Thanks.

Comment: @Reign I have followed the code from the SingleChildScrollView manual, but I still getting issue with putting Expanded inside. I have edited the answer, providing more information. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some code you can test with also with some explanation.

Copy paste and run the code

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView( //Since setting it to scrollable, your widget Column with expanded children wont work as it supposed to be because it wont know its parent height
        //Since its already scrollable `Expanded` will expand or shrink now based on it child widget (Expanded(child: SomeHeight widget)) refer: #10 example
          child: IntrinsicHeight( //This will fix the expanded widget error
            child: Container(
              //Test remove this height
              // height: 400, //But when you set its height before its parent scroll widget, `Expanded` will expand based on its available space 
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100.0),
                  //#10
                  //Experiment with this
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      // height: 100.0, //initialized height, remove parent container height: 400
                      // child: Text("This is also considered as min height"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 100.0),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```